# Is the name "Abdulmanaf" haram?

Tags: halal-haram, naming

In the Islamic Caucasus region of Russia, you can find some men with the name *Абдулманап* (transliterated as *Abdulmanap*). It is not uncommon for loanwords containing the phone /f/ to enter Russian or the languages of the Caucasus as /p/, so I assume *Abdulmanap* is a localized form of the Arabic name عبد المناف. But as far as I can tell, *manaaf* was a pre-Islamic deity, thus meaning the name means that one is a slave to a polytheistic god. In that case, the عبد المناف would be a haram name, correct?

Answer (score 1):

*Abdul* (slave of) should only be paired with a Name of Allah.

> واتفقوا على تحريم كل اسم معبد لغير الله عز وجل كعبد العزى وعبد هبل وعبد عمرو وعبد الكعبة
>
> [Ibn Hazm said:] There is consensus on the prohibition of every name which implies servitude to anyone other than Allah, for example Abdul Uzza, Abdul Hubal, Abdul Umar, Abdul Kaabah
>
> <sup>— [**مراتب الإجماع**](https://archive.org/stream/FP48751/48751#page/n248) ; Chapter الصيد والضحايا والذبائح والعقيقة</sup>

Manap / Manaf is not a name of Allah and it was the name of a false deity, so this name should not be given.